# Choosing MOSFET driver

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, mosfet-driver

I'm new to using high current MOSFETs, and as a result, have never used a MOSFET driver. I am planning on using an [irf100s201](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf100s201.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355da574c1880) MOSEFT to control a LED panel, which draws 35A at 12VDC. This panel will not be controlled via PWM, and will stay on for ~20 minutes at a time.

I have found these two drivers: [ir44252l](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir44252l.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015364c51e8e2a38) and [ucc27519](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc27519.pdf). I know that they will supply the > 10VDC that my FET needs, but am unsure of what other parameters I need to consider. I know that the input capacitance along with the switching time needs to be appropriate, but I can't find the specifications on the driver's datasheet.

Thank you.

Comment: Switching time is only important if switching occurs... if you are not using PWM then there is no switching...

Comment: @peufeu OK, I wasn't sure if it was still relevant due to how long it will take to switch it on, which increases the current draw immediately.

Comment: I mostly agree with @peufeu, but if you switch very slowly, you can blow up your mosfet by holding it in the linear region too long. So you do still want to switch in a reasonably short time. Most likely this will not be difficult unless you do something with really low switching speed.

Comment: @mkeith Yeah, that was what my understanding was. So then, since I'm not doing PWM, either of these drivers will work?

Comment: Yes. One key point is that those are both low-side drivers. So make sure you are placing the NMOS between load and GND. Driving high-side NMOS can be more tricky. Also, you don't need a driver. You can just drive the gate with a couple of cheap transistors. Also, if 12V is available, you can just drive the gate all the way up to 12V. You don't need a 10V supply just for the gate. Finally, you will be dissipating over 4W. It would probably be best to use a small heatsink just to make sure the power FET doesn't overheat.

Comment: @mkeith Yeah exactly. It will be a low side FET, and I will definitely be using a heatsink on it. I'm planning on using 12v on the driver, not 10v

Comment: I have seen FET's that are down around 1mOhm Rds(on). You might avoid a heatsink with a FET like that. Just a thought. Nothing wrong with the heatsink as long as you don't mind the power loss.

Comment: It's important to have enough Vgs to minimize RdsON so driving it with 12V is good. You can also parallel FETs, which results in lower total dissipation.

Comment: Be sure to switch the MOSFET in less than 1 microsecond, to avoid SafeOperatingArea self-destruction. See my answer to this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/322522/high-voltage-pwm-motor-controller-mosfets-explode/322546#322546

Comment: @mkeith Yeah I've found some with much lower just now also. Is there a tradeoff I'm getting by doing that? I know I've read before that it will change the gate capacitance. But does that not matter since I'm not pwm'ing? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I don't think gate capacitance matters for you. It will affect switching time, but since you are not using PWM, switching time is not a major concern as it would be for PWM control. Based on what @analogsystemsrf says, confirm that the drivers will turn on in 1us or less. I suspect they both will do that, but I did not scrutinize the datasheet to verify. Basically, figure out how much charge is required to turn on the MOSFET, then divide that charge by 1us to get Amps, then make sure the driver puts out that many amps (or more).